# Get ClassCastException when generating report with Struts2

Tags: java, struts2, jasper-reports

I put *.jasper* file in my web content folder of my project and in my action class there is only execute method and my *struts.xml* has following code:

```xml
<action name="myJasperTest" class="com.acme.test.action.JasperAction">
    <result name="success" type="jasper">
        <param name="location">/our_jasper_template.jasper</param>
        <param name="dataSource">myList</param>
        <param name="reportParameters">reportParams</param>
        <param name="format">PDF</param>
    </result>
    <result name="error">/Error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

And while running this program it gives me error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle to field
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph.paragraphContainer of type
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParagraphContainer in instance of
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph
```

Can anybody help me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Is it actually deployed? (The library.)

Comment: thanks for attention. but now i have new query? can u help me to resolve my query?

Comment: @Akshay Did you check your report with *iReport* (via preview function)? Is it ok?

Comment: i am using ireport 4.7.0 tool for designing report and i also put jasperreport-4.7.0.jar in my projects lib folder

Comment: finally i done it this error ocuur because of improper jars in my projects lib folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occur due to improper jars in projects lib folder